# How to know the active slave interface in a bonding pair

Tags: c, linux, ethernet

I am working under Linux, with two physical ethernet interfaces.
I have grouped the two interfaces to a bonding interface for backup... and it works.

I would like to know if there is any way to know, from my C user program, what is the active interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `/sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/active_slave` and read it using a program or code of your choice. (Replace path accordingly if using an interface name different from `bond0`.)

Answer (score 0):

Another method to know it (tested on Debian) is looking at the file `/proc/net/bonding/bondX`. Replace bondX with the name of your interface.